# JQuery Randomize image

Tags: jquery, image, random

I am currently using this script to display a random image in one place.

How would I modify this so that I can do the same thing (with different images and alt text) again. So 2 images side by side that are both randomly loaded from different arrarys/locations?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

// Random Image loader //
(function($) {
    $.randomImage = {
        defaults: {
            path: '/imgages/',
            myImages: ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg'],
            myTitles: ['alttext1', 'alttext2']
        }
    }

    $.fn.extend({
        randomImage: function(config) {
            var config = $.extend({}, $.randomImage.defaults, config);
            return this.each(function() {

                var imageNames = config.myImages;
                var imageNamesSize = imageNames.length;
                var lotteryNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageNamesSize);
                var winnerImage = imageNames[lotteryNumber];
                var titleText = config.myTitles[lotteryNumber];
                var fullPath = config.path + winnerImage;

                $(this).attr({
                    src: fullPath,
                    alt: titleText                                                
                });

            });
        }
    });

})(jQuery);

$("#authorImage").randomImage();

});
```

Many thanks

Comment: It's already written to work on more than once element, have you actually tried using it that way? also, when creating plugins, you don't need to wrap it in `$(document).ready(function() {`. That could actually cause more problems than it fixes.

Comment: Ah yes that is an error. I currently have it inline but will be moving it to a js file.

Regarding the multiple image thing. At the minute it only generates one src but I need the function to produce 2 (for 2 elements). I could just duplicate the whole function and re-name it but I wondered if there is an easy way to modify this.

Comment: only generates one src... i don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: the plugin will loop through each selected image, generate a random src from the array, and give the image said src. If you need to use two different arrays, simply call the plugin twice with two different arrays.

Comment: `$("img1").myplugin(options); $("img2").myplugin(options); `

Comment: I can see how it should work. So are you saying I should pass the array values when I call the function?

Comment: well, the plugin isn't built that way currently, but yes that would be ideal.